# unable to proxy requests to server from nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying to proxy the HTTP requests to my application server running on some IP and port through nginx. Here's the configuration I am using in nginx to achieve this:

```
server {
    location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://myserver:9191/api/v1/;
    }
}
```

I am running nginx as a docker container listening to requests on port 4000. Now, when I make a request to my nginx server like so

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/v1/ping
```

I get a 404 error. Logs show this message:

```
2019/06/20 05:33:59 [error] 8#8: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/v1/ping" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/v1/ping HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:4000"
```

Why is nginx not proxying my requests to the application server? And what should I fix in my nginx config file to have successful proxying.

Comment: 1) Would be helpful to see your `docker-compose` file, to see the mapping of directories, 2) If you're trying to access port 4000, where are you basing this line: `proxy_pass http://myserver:9191/api/v1/;` -- are you using an `upstream {}` block? and where does port 9191 come from? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
location ^~ /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9191;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    1000m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, actually the docker image of nginx contained a default.conf file which had the configuration to point to '/' path which was causing it to default to the html folder.